# contrasts error in linear model with one dependent variable and four independent variables

Tags: r, regression

I am new to R coding. I am trying to build a linear model as:

```
lmmodel <- lm(DV ~ IV1 + IV2 + IV3 + IV4)
```

I have a dependent variable with money as data type (decimal value) and 4 independent variables, a mixture of categorical and date:

```
Issuancedate Region Account ClientName Price 
01-01-2015 South Account1 ABC
02-01-2015 North Account2 NA
03-01-2015 NorthEast Account3 BCD
04-01-2015 SouthEast Account4 NA
05-01-2015 NA Account5 M/sBedf
06-01-2015 West Account6 Campus ltd
07-01-2015 SouthWest Account7 Offshoreltd
08-01-2015 NorthWest Account8 Sitenew
```

Price is to be predicted.
I see the below error:

> Error in contrasts<-(tmp, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) :    contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels

Comment: to make it easier for SO to help you, you include a reproducible example. Include your dataset and the code that produce this error.

Comment: In support of Lavoie’s point. Please take the time to read [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to make a great reproducible example in R.

Comment: thanks for the reply,here is the simple code I execute on the sample 8 rows of data.'train<-read.csv("Data.csv")
head(train)
attach(train)
lmmodel<-lm(Price~Account+Region+Issuancedate+ClientName)'
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels

Comment: please update your post instead of using comments

Comment: have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171246/error-in-contrasts-when-defining-a-linear-model-in-r ?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't given us `Price` in your example data, but: the problem is that once all the rows containing `NA` are removed from your data set, one of the categorical dependent variables no longer has more than a single level.  You can't fit a model using a categorical variable with a single level ...