# Another but distinct lme contrast error in terms of factor restrictions

Tags: r, linear-regression, lme4, factors

I'm running a linear mixed model and keep getting the error -

```
 Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

First off I have reviewed the helpful link - [Error in contrasts when defining a linear model in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171246/error-in-contrasts-when-defining-a-linear-model-in-r)

Yet when I try various means of assessing my factor levels, `summary(df)`, `is.factor(df$variable)`, `nlevels(df$variable)` and the suggested `ifelse(n <- sapply(m, function(x) length(levels(x))) == 1, "DROP", "NODROP")`The latter for example gives me "NODROP" on every variable. While nlevel(df$variable) states 2, Summary(df) accurately quantifies how many rows are in each of the 2 levels of this factor too.

Consistently I see the specific variable that is stopping the model run (when I remove it, the model runs without issue) be noted as having 2 factors which is correct and in my mind should run. I've had no issues running this exact model with a different binary factor variable, but this one seems to consistently run into this factor issue that doesn't make sense to me given the checks seemingly confirming that R is treating the column as a 2-level factor.

Is there something I can do to resolve this seeming error that wasn't mentioned in the prior thread? There are no exotic characters - simply "CB" and "BA" which are tissue region identifiers.

The exact line of code is below.

```
models <- dlply(Controls, "PROTEIN", function(df) lmer(ABUNDANCE ~ REGION + PMI + AGE + (1|PEPTIDE), data=df, REML=FALSE))
```

REGION is the problem child. I tried `options(lmerControl=list(check.nlev.gtr.1 = "ignore"))`to no avail as well.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: It looks like you checked the number of levels per variable, but possibly not the number of levels per variable *within* each "PROTEIN" group.  Since you're fitting a model separately for each protein group this is the level you  must do your checks at.

Comment: Ah thank you. I realized it was related to the number of levels per variable within each protein. Much appreciated. Just need to figure out how to filter by that now, many thanks again!