# "Contrasts apply only to factors" error when running ANOVA

Tags: r, lm, anova

I have a data frame that looks like the following:

```
goal  behavior  dv1  dv2  dv3
1     1         4    2    6
1     5         3    5    1
1     7         2    4    2
5     1         5    2    7
5     5         2    1    3
5     7         2    1    2
7     1         4    5    7
7     5         2    1    4
7     7         3    2    5
```

As you can see, there are 9 conditions (3 possibilities for goal x 3 possibilities for behavior). In the actual data set, there are approximately 25-30 participants for each of the 9 conditions. I am trying to run two-way [anova](/questions/tagged/anova)'s on the dependent variables (`dv1`, `dv2`, and `dv3`) in this example to see if there is an interaction between `goal` and `behavior`.

I have tried running the following code. `dv` is a matrix that just includes columns `dv1`, `dv2`, `dv3`. `df` is the entire data frame above.

```
output <- lm(as.matrix(dv) ~ goal * behavior, data = df,
         contrasts = list(goal = contr.sum, behavior = contr.sum))
summary(aov(output))
```

When I try to create the object `output`, I get the following error:

> Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contrasts.arg[[nn]]) :
>   contrasts apply only to factors

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171246/error-in-contrasts-when-defining-a-linear-model-in-r) but am still unable to solve my problem. When I run the following code, I am told that none of my variables are considered to be factors. I am not sure why this is when both "goal" and "behavior" have 3 levels each with variation.

```
factor <- sapply((df), function(x) is.factor(x))
```

The other questions I've looked at on here specifically address the error message of

> contrasts apply only to factors with two or more levels

which is different than the error message I received. What can I do to get this to run properly?

Comment: Your toy example worked just fine for me after: `df <- df %>% transmute_all(as.factor)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"factor" has a specific meaning in R (e.g. see [this page from UC Berkeley](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/factors.html)); they're not just any variable that varies, but variables that are encoded so that R knows it's supposed to treat them as categorical predictors.

In your case,

```
df <- transform(df, goal=factor(goal), behavior=factor(behavior))
```

should work (`factor()` and `as.factor()` are approximately the same, use whichever you prefer). The suggestion from comments (`df <- df %>% transmute_all(as.factor)`) is a little more compact, but (1) depends on the "tidyverse" suite of packages (which you might not prefer) and (2) changes *all* variables within the data frame to factor (ditto).