# How you can make a list from a date frame and then a regression?

Tags: r, list, regression, glm

I have a DF with 4 columns. In the first column are stations and in the other 3 columns are time, weekday and number of people.
My goal is to make a regression(glm) for every single station. I think with a list it would be easier or?
My question is, how do I make a list and how do I do the regression(glm) for each station using the list?

my Df looks like this:

here is a picture of my DF
[image]

### Example code:

*TrainStation* is chr, *Weekday* and *timeOfday* are factors and *NumberOfPassenger* is num.

```
    TrainStation<-c("East","North","East","North","North","Central","North","Central","East","North","East","North","Central","North","Central","North","Central","North","Central","North","Central","North","Central","East","North","East","North","Central","North","Central","East","North","East","North","Central","East")
TimeOfday<-c(12,12,8,16,10,6,0,7,1,3,23,15,12,8,16,10,1,3,5,7,9,10,12,11,17,2,4,5,13,14,18,19,20,21,22,23)
Date<-sample(seq(as.Date('2019/01/01'), as.Date('2019/02/28'), by="day"), 36)
Date<-as.character(Date)
DF<-cbind(TrainStation,TimeOfday,Date)
DF<-as.data.frame(DF)

#Weekdays
DF$Date<-as.Date(DF$Date)
DF$Date<-weekdays(DF$Date)
#TimeOfday
DF$TimeOfday<-strptime(DF$TimeOfday,format = "%H")
DF$TimeOfday<-hour(DF$TimeOfday)

DF$TrainStation<-as.character(DF$TrainStation)
DF$TimeOfday<-as.factor(DF$TimeOfday)
DF$Date<-as.factor(DF$Date)

#Data for regression
library(tidyverse)
DF2<-DF%>%
  group_by(TrainStation,Date,TimeOfday)%>%
  summarize(NumberOfPassenger = n_distinct(TrainStation))
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: It would be helpful to have the data in a workable format. Can you post the output of `dput(your_dataframe)`?

Comment: It's nicely illustrated in the book [R for Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html).

Comment: What should the regression look like?
```Weekday = b0 + b1* timeofday + b2 * numberofpassenger```?

Comment: The glm should look like this (for every Station): glm(NumberOfPassenger~TimeOfday+Date, family = poisson)

Comment: Thank you!I posted a Example code

Answer (score 1):

Using your data this is what you could do:

You data

```
TrainStation<-c("East","North","East","North","North","Central","North","Central","East","North","East","North","Central","North","Central","North","Central","North","Central","North","Central","North","Central","East","North","East","North","Central","North","Central","East","North","East","North","Central","East")
TimeOfday<-c(12,12,8,16,10,6,0,7,1,3,23,15,12,8,16,10,1,3,5,7,9,10,12,11,17,2,4,5,13,14,18,19,20,21,22,23)
Date<-sample(seq(as.Date('2019/01/01'), as.Date('2019/02/28'), by="day"), 36)
Date<-as.character(Date)
DF<-cbind(TrainStation,TimeOfday,Date)
DF<-as.data.frame(DF)

#Weekdays
DF$Date<-as.Date(DF$Date)
DF$Date<-weekdays(DF$Date)
#TimeOfday
DF$TimeOfday<-strptime(DF$TimeOfday,format = "%H")
DF$TimeOfday<-hour(DF$TimeOfday)

DF$TrainStation<-as.character(DF$TrainStation)
DF$TimeOfday<-as.factor(DF$TimeOfday)
DF$Date<-as.factor(DF$Date)

#Data for regression
library(tidyverse)
DF2<-DF%>%
  group_by(TrainStation,Date,TimeOfday)%>%
  summarize(NumberOfPassenger = n_distinct(TrainStation))
```

Now moving into the modeling section you can use nested column and then apply your model

```
DF2 %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(TrainStation) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(model = map(data, ~glm(NumberOfPassenger~TimeOfday+Date, family = poisson(), data = .)))
```

That will give you something that looks like:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  TrainStation data              model    
  <chr>        <list>            <list>   
1 Central      <tibble [11 x 3]> <S3: glm>
2 East         <tibble [9 x 3]>  <S3: glm>
3 North        <tibble [16 x 3]> <S3: glm>
```

Which has all of the nested features. If you want to extract the model parameters for each station you could do something like:

```
TrainStation<-c("East","North","East","North","North","Central","North","Central","East","North","East","North","Central","North","Central","North","Central","North","Central","North","Central","North","Central","East","North","East","North","Central","North","Central","East","North","East","North","Central","East")
TimeOfday<-c(12,12,8,16,10,6,0,7,1,3,23,15,12,8,16,10,1,3,5,7,9,10,12,11,17,2,4,5,13,14,18,19,20,21,22,23)
Date<-sample(seq(as.Date('2019/01/01'), as.Date('2019/02/28'), by="day"), 36)
Date<-as.character(Date)
DF<-cbind(TrainStation,TimeOfday,Date)
DF<-as.data.frame(DF)

#Weekdays
DF$Date<-as.Date(DF$Date)
DF$Date<-weekdays(DF$Date)
#TimeOfday
DF$TrainStation<-as.character(DF$TrainStation)

DF$TimeOfday<-as.factor(DF$TimeOfday)
DF$Date<-as.factor(DF$Date)

#Data for regression
library(tidyverse)
DF2<-DF%>%
  group_by(TrainStation,Date,TimeOfday)%>%
  summarize(NumberOfPassenger = n_distinct(TrainStation))

DF2 %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(TrainStation) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(model = map(data, ~glm(NumberOfPassenger~TimeOfday+Date, family = poisson(), data = .))) %>% 
  mutate(tidy_model = map(model, broom::tidy)) %>% 
  select(TrainStation, tidy_model) %>% 
  unnest(tidy_model)
```

In order to give you all of the parameters from the model for each stations

```
# A tibble: 35 x 6
   TrainStation term           estimate std.error statistic p.value
   <chr>        <chr>             <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 Central      (Intercept)    4.68e-11     1.000  4.68e-11   1.000
 2 Central      TimeOfday12   -3.19e-35     1.41  -2.26e-35   1    
 3 Central      TimeOfday14    5.24e-34     1.41   3.70e-34   1    
 4 Central      TimeOfday16    1.03e-34     1.41   7.28e-35   1    
 5 Central      TimeOfday22   -5.21e-18     2.00  -2.61e-18   1    
 6 Central      TimeOfday5    -5.21e-18     1.41  -3.68e-18   1    
 7 Central      TimeOfday6     2.17e-34     1.41   1.53e-34   1
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. It works in this example but in the original data I get: Error: evaluation error contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels. I have only two factors(Timeofday and weekday) and they have 24 and 7 levels

Comment: This could occur if you have missing data, unused levels, see <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44200195/how-to-debug-contrasts-can-be-applied-only-to-factors-with-2-or-more-levels-er> and <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171246/error-in-contrasts-when-defining-a-linear-model-in-r>